# AWS CDK, creating an alias record for existing cloud front distribution in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK ( Python ) to create an Alias record targeted to existing cloud front distribution which has been provisioned in different AWS Account and different Route53 Hosted zone.

I am importing existing CF Distribution and public Route53 Zone  via below CDK Code.

```
    existinghostezone=route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(self,"existinghostedzone",
            hosted_zone_id="HOSTEDZONE-ID",
            zone_name ="ZONENAME")

    existingdist=cloudfront.Distribution.from_distribution_attributes(self,"existingdist",
         distribution_id="DISTRIBUTION-ID",
           domain_name="DISTRIBUTION-DOMAIN-NAME" 
           )
```

Below is the code where I am creating a new route53 hosted zone and trying to create route53 A record that points to the imported cloud front distribution above.

```
#Creating new route53 zone

newZone=route53.HostedZone(self,"newZone",
                zone_name="new-zone-name",
                comment="Managed by CloudFormation")

#Creating alias entry config 

my_alias = route53.IAliasRecordTarget.bind(
            self,
            record=route53.AliasRecordTargetConfig(
               hosted_zone_id= existinghostezone.hosted_zone_id,
               dns_name=existingdist.domain_name)
            ) 

#Creating route53 a record

aRecord=route53.ARecord(self,"aRecord",
         target=route53.RecordTarget(my_alias),
         zone=newZone.hosted_zone_id,
         record_name="new-record-name",
         comment="Managed by CloudFormation"
         )
```

Now when I try to run `cdk synth` on the above code , I am getting following error message.

```
packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 332, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected object reference, got "${Token[TOKEN.58]}"
```

As I am new to the AWS CDK ( Python ), I just really don't know what does the above error mean.

I have also tried to create an Alias  record with below method as well

```
#Creating new route53 zone
newZone=route53.HostedZone(self,"newZone",
                zone_name="new-zone-name",
                comment="Managed by CloudFormation")

#Creating alias entry config 

my_alias = route53.IAliasRecordTarget.bind(
            self,
            record=route53.AliasRecordTargetConfig(
               hosted_zone_id= existinghostezone.hosted_zone_id,
               dns_name=existingdist.domain_name)
            ) 

#Creating route53 a record

aRecord=route53.ARecord(self,"aRecord",
         target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(my_alias),
         zone=newZone.hosted_zone_id,
         record_name="new-record-name",
         comment="Managed by CloudFormation"
         )
```

Now when I try to run cdk synth on the above code , I am getting following error message.

```
raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Got 'undefined' for non-optional instance of {"name":"aliasTarget","type":{"fqn":"@aws-cdk/aws-route53.IAliasRecordTarget"}}
```

I have tried to find some examples that uses the existing cloud front distribution as an Alias entry however every one has different methods and answers which aren't working for me.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your [ARecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.ARecord.html), you'll want to provide the zone object ([IHostedZone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.IHostedZone.html)) for the [`zone`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.ARecord.html#zone) property

Try with:

```py
aRecord = route53.ARecord(self,"aRecord",
    target=route53.RecordTarget(my_alias),
    zone=newZone,  # rather than newZone.hosted_zone_id
    record_name="new-record-name",
    comment="Managed by CloudFormation"
)
```

Comment: this works ! I am wondering if there is any way to debug the cdk code, that tells me where I am making this sorta mistakes.

Comment: I imagine that further up in your stack trace in the error it would have pointed to the line where you define the `route53.ARecord`